# How do I assign alarms to scaling policies in scaling group using aws-sdk

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I'm using a ruby script to help facilitate managing AutoScaling on AWS EC2. I've managed to create `AMI`s, create `LaunchConfigurations`, create `ScalingGroups`, and associating one another.

I'm trying to clone a scaling group, copying its launch configurations, load balancers, etc. and its scaling policies.

To copy its scaling policy I have this code:

```
orig_scaling_group.scaling_policies.each do |policy|
  props = Hash[%i(adjustment_type scaling_adjustment cooldown min_adjustment_step alarms).map { |s| [s, policy.send(s)] }.reject { |k, v| v.nil? }]
  clone_scaling_group.scaling_policies[policy.name].put(props)
end
```

(scaling_groups are instances of `AWS::AutoScaling::Group`)

This goes over the original's scaling policies, and extracts the data from it, and sets it as a new policy in the clone scaling group.

This works fine, except that it does not copy the alarms to the new policy. I could not find anyway in which I can programmatically assign an alarm to a scaling policy.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I could not find anyway in which I can programmatically assign an alarm to a scaling policy.

I will be restricting my response to above statement.

In [AWS Core Ruby SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/CloudWatch/V20100801.html), under [`put_metric_alarm-instance_method`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/CloudWatch/V20100801.html#put_metric_alarm-instance_method) API, you can use `alarm_actions` method. From above referred documentation:

[image]

Please note that, above information is relevant to **AWS CORE SDK Ruby** and not the older *AWS ruby SDK*.

Also for AWS-CLI, the similar settings can be found with [put-metric-alarm](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/put-metric-alarm.html) for `--alarm-actions` option.

Not sure whether this what you are looking for, but here I can certainly see a programmatic way of assigning an alarm to an Autoscaling policy.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Found the relevant API in the `aws-sdk` under `AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm.put(...)` you need to copy all the current attributes of the alarm into it as well... yuck.